# Check if the mouse is within an element's boundary in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a `div` with `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events.
Also, I am tracking the mouse position within a `useEffect` hook which updates the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const mouseMove = (e) => {
      setMousePosition({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    };
  }, []);
```

When the mouse enters the `div`, I get the element position with `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method.

```
const isMouseInBound = (ref) => {
    const el = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    let ret = false;

    if ( mousePosition.x >= el.left && mousePosition.x <= el.right) {
      ret = true;
    }else{
      ret = false;
    }
    console.log(ret);
  };
```

FYI: the `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method returns an object like the one bellow:

```
{
  x: 16,
  y: 0,
  width: 358.65625,
  height: 300,
  top: 0,
  right: 374.65625,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 16
}
```

I want to log to the console `true` when the mouse is within the div's boundaries or `false` on the mouse leaves.

I am comparing the mouse x position (stored in the state) to the left and right values from the object above, but I think the state is not updated fast enough to get an accurate reading.

I only get an accurate reading by moving the mouse slowly.

Here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-world-9o0utp?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `isMouseInBound` function, dont use your `mousePosition` state, you can use event client position

```
const isMouseInBound = (e) => {
    const eleBounds = boxRef1.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    let ret = false;
    if (e.clientX >= eleBounds.left && e.clientX <= eleBounds.right) {
        ret = true;
    } else {
        ret = false;
    }
    console.log(ret);
};

<div
    id="boxRef1"
    ref={boxRef1}
    onMouseEnter={isMouseInBound}
    style={{
        background: 'grey',
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
    }}
/>
```